# how do we refer to a work of an author written in English?

Tags: vocabulary

Which of the following is correct?

> 1. English work of an author?
> 2. English speaking work of an author?
> 3. author's work in English language?

Is there a specific term instead of work, if I only mean one book?

Comment: The book is in English.

Comment: How is it if I want to put in a sentence like "we are going to present two historians’ works written in the English language?" I don't mean that the presentation is going to be in English, but the books are.

Comment: *We are going to present two historians' books that have been written in English.*

Comment: "We are going to present two historians’ works written in the English language" 0r "in English." Both are fine. The first one sounds more formal.